# svm predict function always return a large number

Tags: opencv, svm, predict

I trying to implement a simple sample, the purpose is tranning and detect a number. Source as following:

**Step 1: Initial data for tranning:**
I used a collect of images number for traning data,

```
    Mat vectorMatToMat(vector<Mat> list) {
        if (list.empty()) {
            return Mat();
        }
        int row = list.size();
        int col = list.at(0).rows * list.at(0).cols;
        Mat data(row, col, CV_32FC1);
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            Mat rowMat = list.at(i).reshape(1, 1);
            rowMat.copyTo(data.row(i));
        }
        return data;
    }
    Mat vectorIntToMat(vector<int> list) {
        int row = list.size();
        Mat data(row, 1, CV_32SC1, &list[0]);
        return data;
    }

    Mat dataMat = vectorMatToMat(listImageForTraining);
    Mat dataLabel = vectorIntToMat(listLabel);
```

**Step 2: Init SVM:**

```
Ptr<TrainData> trainData = TrainData::create(dataMat, ROW_SAMPLE, dataLabel);

Ptr<SVM> model = SVM::create();
model->setType(SVM::C_SVC);
model->setKernel(SVM::LINEAR);
model->setC(7);
model->setNu(SVM::NU_SVC);
model->setP(0);
model->setDegree(0);
model->setGamma(20);
model->setCoef0(0);
TermCriteria term(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER +CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 1000, 1e-6);
model->setTermCriteria(term);
model->train(trainData);
```

**Step 3: trying using SVM for predict:**

```
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        Mat check = dataMat.row(i);
        ostringstream oss;
        oss << i;
        imshow(oss.str(), check.reshape(1, 128));

        check = check.reshape(1, 1);
        int lable = svm.predict(check);

        cout << "Result: " << lable << endl;
    }
```

**Step 4: Result:**

```
Result: -1237234688
Result: 159407376
Result: 159407376
Result: 167908848
Result: 1065353216
Result: 1065353216
Result: 1065353216
Result: 1065353216
Result: 1065353216
Result: 1065353216
Result: 1065353216
Result: 1065353216
Result: 1065353216
Result: 1065353216
Result: 1065353216
```

As we can see, my result are very large number, although my labels are numbers in 0 to 10.
I can not understand why, i think i have a mistake when I init SVM model.

But i dont know how to fix this issue,
If there is any idea, please help me.

Thanks & Best Regards,

Thiep

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have mistake in first step in following method:

```
Mat vectorIntToMat(vector<int> list) {
    int row = list.size();
    Mat data(row, 1, CV_32SC1, &list[0]);
    return data;
}
```

You pass vector of labels by value. It actually make a copy of label's vector which will be destructed after return.
Than you use following constructor of `cv::Mat`:

```
Mat::Mat(int rows, int cols, int type, void* data, size_t step=AUTO_STEP)
```

According to [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-mat), this constructor doesn't allocate matrix data. It just use memory which you provide. But in your case this memory will be freed after method return and label's matrix object will be incorrect.

Obviously, if you use incorrect label's matrix on training you get incorrect prediction results.

I think, the simplest fix of the problem is following:

```
Mat vectorIntToMat(vector<int> list) {
    int row = list.size();
    Mat data = Mat(row, 1, CV_32SC1, &list[0]).clone();
    return data;
}
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.

I tried create an array and pass it in the constructor.

But the result is the same with my above result. :(

Answer (score 0):

I tried modified as following, but the result is still not good.

```
Mat vectorIntToMat(vector<int> list) {
    int row = list.size();
    Mat data = Mat(row, 1, CV_32SC1, &list[0]).clone();
    return data;
}
```

After that I tried modify as following, and my issue solved:

```
Mat vectorIntToMat(vector<int> list) {
    return Mat(list, true);
}
```

But I still don't understand the root cause.
Anybody can explain for me?

Comment: Could you please check that example with `.clone()` not works? I made a simple code shippet and both variant works the same. May be you changed code somewhere else?